# LaTeX Listing Not Visible

Tags: latex, lstlisting

I am using the listings package, but only the caption is showing, not the inner text. The code is definitely not showing anywhere in the document, including after downloading the PDF (I'm using overleaf). I have the following (simplified to core elements) code:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={irace Parameters}, label={lst:irace}]
example
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But all that is showing is the below (text above listing caption and below for context).

[image]

Comment: Anyone using Overleaf should also refer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55617/141466).

Comment: @YushanZHANG you should probably add that as an answer, I for one would upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is actually working fine, but only on my windows 8.1 workstation laptop, but not working on my windows 10 office pc. I assume this is an issue with Overleaf v2.

Answer (score 3):

Solution to me was hidden in the [comment of Yushan ZHANG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382819/latex-listing-not-visible#comment112621030_51382819):
Not only in overleaf but also locally the `listings` package does not properly work with the `draft` option. Passing `final` to the package fixes the issue.

```
\usepackage[final]{listings}
```